# iTunes.Connect delivers white empty page

Tags: app-store-connect

I can't login to iTunes.connect anymore. It delivers an empty white page since the whole day now. There is no 401 and no 404, just plain html that renders an empty page:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhIy6OeaBZY&feature=youtu.be

My friends can log into itunes connect and see the real page, but not me. 
I tried different browsers, cleared cache and everything else.

What to do now? Apple isn't interested in this issue because it works for lot of people apparently....

Comment: Exactly my situation today as shown in your video.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything you can do about it on your end, but I wouldn't panic. I believe it may be traffic and/or account related. We have it happen every now and then and usually after a couple of hours things are back to normal. Should the issue persist, I absolutely would contact Apple regarding it though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramsay also commented, some more people had this issue yesterday...

How i ended up with this: i switched the network to 3G UMTS where everything worked fine. 
Then I disconnected the router for a while to achieve an IP-address-change from my provider for my office. But iTunes.Connect then worked only in incognito mode, so i had to clear browser cache with cookies again. Now it works.

Apparently iTunes.Connect had some serious issues in general. The processing-state for a new release in the internal-testing-phase of Testflight took more than 5 hours yesterday. Usually 10 minutes where enough to process.